# Camel asynchronous call get the response

Tags: apache-camel

I am making an asynchronous call to a webservice using apache camel API using below code:

```
    Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
    Message msg = exchange.getIn();
    msg.setBody(requestStr);
    msg.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

    template.asyncCallback("direct:invokeAPI", exchange, new Synchronization() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Exchange exchange) {
            System.out.println("Success");
            System.out.println(exchange);
            System.out.println(exchange.getIn());
            System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
            System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
            System.out.println("================================");
            System.out.println(exchange.getOut());
            System.out.println(exchange.getOut().getHeaders());
            System.out.println(exchange.getOut().getBody());
            System.out.println("================================");
            Exception ex = exchange.getException();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exchange exchange) {
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
    });
```

Now my webservice is failing with an exception and it is returning a json response:

```
Response-Code: 500
Content-Type: application/json
Headers: {Content-Type=[application/json], Date=[Fri, 03 Aug 2018 13:18:19 GMT]}
Payload: {"errorMessage":"Unable to process","errorCode":"500"}
```

Now how can I capture this information in my `template.asyncCallback` method.
In my above code it is going to `onComplete` callback method and printing below messages :

```
Success
Exchange[ID-xxxx-0-2]
Message[ID-xxxx-0-1]
{breadcrumbId=ID-xxxx-0-1, content-type=application/json}
{
"source":"PDF"
}
================================
Message[]
{}
null
================================
```

I am trying to get the status 500 code and the response payload that has the error information, but I am not able to print anything. Can you please help me what is the correct way to get the error information.

Comment: Which component are you using for the REST call? I cant see the whole route here.

Comment: @Namphibian, I am using Spring with Apache Camel API, is that what you are asking? Please let me know if anything else needed.